# Divider plugin for Cinema 4D in Blender with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

For Cinema 4D there is a plugin called "Divider - Cinema 4D fragmentation plugin" that creates a modular Mondrian-style topology:

[image]
<sub>[(Image Source)](https://karpik.gumroad.com/l/VeCmP)</sub>

The effect is procedural and can also be animated. This video shows what is possible with it and which parameters are available:
[Divider plugin for Cinema 4D: Developer's tips and tricks](https://youtu.be/5vQS3ICGgzY?t=133)

Is there a way to do similar things in Blender with *Geometry Nodes*?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.